# Best way for keeping dynamically allocated array without bothering about deletion?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost

This is what I need:

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
        : ptr_(new char[1000])
    {}

    ~A()
    {
        delete [] ptr_;
    }

private:
    char* ptr_;
};
```

The problem with it is - I have to write copy constructor, and also assignment operator. I don't want to do that, so I use shared_array:

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
        : array_(new char[1000])
    {}

private:
    boost::shared_array<char> array_;
};
```

The issue with this is - I have to use array_.get() in all places, because I need bore pointer to the buffer. So I introduces also another pointer:

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
        : array_(new char[1000])
        , bore_ptr_(array_.get())
    {}

private:
    boost::shared_array<char> array_;
    char* const bore_ptr_;
};
```

My question is - is there a better way to do this?
The thing that I don't like in the final solution is - I keep shared_array, but I don't use it. It's just for cleaning things.

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::vector`?

Comment: Then I should use `&(array_[0])`, this isn't so comfortable either, I think. I'm working with pointers.

Comment: You can use `vec.data()`, but why do you need the bare pointer in the first place? Are you communicating with a C API?

Comment: Ok, how is your class supposed to be used? Can you write some use cases you'd be comfortable with? Anyway, returning a pointer to object's internal data is not a good choice.

Comment: but why do you need the bare pointer in the first place - if you don't know the answer, don't try to convince me not to use pointers, that's what I need. I don't return, I use internally.

Comment: This is exactly what `std::vector` does best. Failing that use `std::unique_ptr<[]>`.

Comment: Guys you don't get me, thanks anyway.

Comment: It sound like you want to use *something* without having to actually use it.

Comment: @user1289 if several people "don't get you", you should probably put more effort in your question

Comment: @user1289 *I have to write copy constructor, and also assignment operator. I don't want to do that* -- All of the "I don't want to.." statements in your question and further comments just leads to the answers that are given.  The language has its limits, and you have to accept those limits.

Comment: That dreadful `bore_ptr_` might become a dangling pointer (you should never introduce a reference (pointer) to a member for convenience)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at unique_ptr or shared_ptr.
There is no real need to use boost for smart pointers, as C++11 and onwards come with their own set which handle themselves greatly..

you can use unique_ptr for example, which will give you the syntactic sugar you require, as you can work with a smart pointer (unique or shared) in the same way you would work with a regular one. So, simply swap out shared_array with either one of these.

Comment: Have a look at my question, I need array, and I don't want to use get() every time.

Comment: Sorry,  didn't load fully I guess.

Comment: @user1289 You don't have to use `get()` every time. Just store keep a copy of the raw pointer and use that

Comment: Look at my question please.

Answer (score 1):

If your class is supposed to expose a function that returns a raw pointer, just return `array_.get`:

```
const char* GetPtr() const
{
    return array_.get();
}
```

Within class, you can always use this function. Or, if you want to use `bore_ptr_` instead you need to ensure it gets updated wherever smart pointer gets updated. I would however suggest that you shouldn't have another bogus variable just for the sake of typing less code. Maintaining the bore-ptr would be more prone to error in future and is definitely not part of class as valid data.

You may choose `vector`, `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` also. But logic would remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

Best way for keeping dynamically allocated array without bothering about deletion is to use a `std::vector<char>`:

```
class A {
  std::vector<char> array_;
  char* const bore_ptr_;
public:
  A() : array_(1000), bore_ptr_(array_.data()) {}
};
```

Comment: I really don't like it, what happen if the vector has been reallocated the bore_ptr_ will be invalidated. The request of the OP to do not type .data() everywhere (frankly very weak reason) should be shadow by programm correctness

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi The vector won't be reallocated take a look at the constructor in the example it already pre-allocates the buffer.

Comment: keeping std::vector only for using it's buffer is nonsense.

Comment: @user1289 not as nonsense as keeping a `boost::shared_array` with its fancy reference counting.

Comment: I think it is. I need something to delete it after me, shared_array does it, but vector definitely isn't supposed for that.

Comment: @101010 if I look solely at the code you provide the vector is not very useful either. You need to populate it and accessing it in some way. What I am saying that it is dangerous, for not practical benefit (saving keystrokes is never a good reason)

Comment: @user1289 Don't use it then, a future reader though might find it useful.

Comment: @user1289 vector is supposed exactly for managing the memory of an array buffer. Sure it is supposed also for growing the buffer automatically, but there is no penalty in not using the feature. Shared array on the other hand is supposed for **sharing** the array. And the reference counting does have some overhead that you're paying for. (note that I'm not trying to convince you to use `std::vector` either. I'm just pointing out a flaw in your argument).

Comment: @user1289 The *only* reason for a vector is its buffer. Its a flexible buffer that does all the error prone fiddly stuff so you don't have to. But its still just a buffer.